# gThumb Video Rotation

Tags: video, extension, metadata, playback, gthumb

I have rotated a video using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 output.mp4
```

and

```
exiftool -rotation=270 FILE.mp4
```

as I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding) answer. But gThumb does not honour this change in metadata (in both cases). Both totem and VLC honour this metadata.

How can I set gThumb to honour this metadata and rotate this video?

Comment: If there isn't a setting, it's entirely possible that gThumb doesn't have the ability to read the metadata and rotate the video based on that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is what I want to know. Is there any setting or extension which makes gThumb honour the rotation metadata?